# Calling secure Web Api from Xamarin.Ios not working

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, xamarin.ios, authorization

I am trying to access a secured web api on my server that requires authentication(Google/Facebook) from an Xamarin.Ios app.

Downloading and running the sample ToDo App from the azure portal, and adding the authentication as in this tutorial https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-ios-get-started-users/ works like a charm using google and facebook.

But when I create a quick ASP.NET application and add a Web Api 2 Controller, and trying to call it from the Xamarin.Ios, it dose not even reach it.

For example, have this controller:

```
public class GetAdviceController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    [ResponseType(typeof(string))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAdvice()
    {
        return Ok("RandomAdvice/Passed");
    }
}
```

And this code in Xamarin.Ios

```
    public MobileServiceClient Client = new MobileServiceClient(Constants.ApplicationURL);
    HttpClient restClient= new HttpClient();

        try
        {
            MobileServiceUser User = await App.Client.LoginAsync(this, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google);
            //User contains the Token and SID

            Console.Error.WriteLine(@"Logged IN");

            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            try
            {
                response = await client.GetAsync("https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/api/getadvice");

     //The response is 200 but it does not reach my controller and redirests me to the login screen of the asp.net website. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv1l9.jpg


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine( ex.Message);
            }
```

The response.content is https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv1l9.jpg just in JSON format.

I am sure I am missing something but I just can`t find what it is.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you set the token in any header anywhere? I don't see anything that indicates this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should check both sides: server and client:

**On Server**, make sure you have `[MobileAppController]` for the Web API Controller

```
[MobileAppController]
public class GetAdviceController : ApiController
{
}
```

Client **Xamarin**, if you want to use classic `HttpClient` for making request to Web API (Azure server), need to add few Headers:

```
HttpClient restClient= new HttpClient();
restClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add (new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue ("application/json"));
restClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add ("ZUMO-API-VERSION", "2.0.0");
restClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add ("X-ZUMO-AUTH", token);
restClient.GetAsync(....);
```

Use `token` from User object that you've authenticated with Google